# How can I get false from the boolean expression that contains undefined instead of an error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is a function:

```js
function isInvalid(value: any): boolean {
    return (value < min || value > max || value.length < minlength || value.length > maxlength || !pattern.test(value));
}
```

How to make the function return `true` as long as any of the conditions are met, for example, when `value` is less than `min` **OR** is larger than `max`?

The real problem is, the value on the right **can be undefined**, but at least one of them is defined. In this case, I will always get exception messages such as `ReferenceError: min is not defined`. Is it possible to skip conditions that will throw the `ReferenceError` and keep judging until the expression returns a real boolean?

Maybe the language is not so clear, it can be imagined as

> if `value < min` throws the `ReferenceError`, ignore it and judge the next(`value > max`), if it also throws the error, then ignore it again and go next, etc. When a certain condition, maybe `value.length > maxlength`, returns a real boolean `true`, then return it to the function.

Comment: They are not even declared. Now I think my idea is actually impossible :/

Comment: When there is a possibility that there will be variables with undefined values you can use a 'truthy' check to determine if the value has a value or is FALSE, '', 0, NULL, or undefined.  However, in this case you  may just want to use the typeof function which returns 'undefined' if the variable is undefined.   Putting this test ahead, either in the same if-expression or in an if-then statement that encloses the one you show, allows you to handle these conditions without an error occurring.

Comment: what are you using this function for and what are you trying to achieve? seems to me like there is a better solution to this than dealing with possibly undefined variables, but you must provide some context so we can figure out a better implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `typeof` check right before checking the condition with `&&`:

```
function isInvalid(value: any): boolean {
    return (
      (typeof min !== 'undefined' && value < min) ||
      (typeof max !== 'undefined' && value > max) ||
      (typeof minlength !== 'undefined' && value.length < minlength) ||
      (typeof maxlength !== 'undefined' && value.length > maxlength) || 
      !pattern.test(value)
    );
}
```

Also note that for Typescript, there's no need to specify the return type if the compiler can infer it from the function's code, so feel free to leave out the `: boolean` if you want.

That said, it's a code smell not to be sure if a variable will be declared at a certain point or not. Better to pass arguments to `isInvalid` if you can.

If you aren't afraid of `undefined` being a local variable in the outer scope (exceedingly rare), you can trim it down to

```
  (min !== undefined && value < min) ||
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for asking! I had already thought about it, but I think it's kind of complicated. Is there any easier solution?

Comment: The fact that you aren't sure if a variable will be declared or not at a given point in the code is the real issue - that's quite strange, and results in weird-looking code like this. Can you pass arguments to `isInvalid` instead?

Comment: Yep, I think passing arguments to it is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `min` and `max` variable before expression maybe?

```
return (typeof min !== 'undefined' && value < min || ... );
```

Or simply do this, but be careful that it will fail if variable value has falsy value like `0`, `false`, `null` and `""`:

```
return (min && value < min || max && value > max || ...);
```